# How to receive url From Browser in an activity using intents in Monodroid

Tags: android, android-intent, xamarin.android

I have successfully configured the Intent Filters which allows the browser on "share link" to pop-up my app. However, the handling part is the problem.

```
string g;
var action = Intent.Action;

if (Intent.ActionSend == action)
{
     g = Intent.GetStringExtra(Intent.ExtraText);    
}
```

Tried the upper part along with many other implementations but it didn't work( The app force-closes). In Android, intent i =getintent(), seems to get the job down but in Monodroid there is now direct get method.

There is however, intent i = new intent (intent.getintent(string));  in monodroid but is not quite getting the job done. Please help (using pro version of monodroid and testing on a device).

Answer (score 0):

The parameter to `GetStringExtra` should not be `Intent.ExtraText`, but instead whatever the name of the extra that you put in earlier. For example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.PutExtra("someKey", someStringValue);
...
// In another activity
var value = Intent.GetStringExtra("someKey");
```

Comment: Wouldn't The above mentioned method work on;y if I was sending a string from one activity to another?. In my question, I was asking to get the URL string from the Android's Stock browser (you know when you tap on a link and a "Share page" option pops out).How to do that ?